# Jenkins Plugin having trouble using Class?

Tags: java, jenkins, oauth-2.0, jenkins-plugins, scribe

I'm trying to integrate scribe-java and write a Jenkins Plugin for it, but it seems Jenkins can't be used with Class? Does anyone know why is this?

Jenkins Plugin code:

```
    OAuthService service =
            new ServiceBuilder().provider( com.lookout.jenkins.publishoverbox.BoxApi20.class ).apiKey( clientId ).apiSecret(clientSecret ).callback(callbackUrl).grantType( OAuthConstants.AUTHORIZATION_CODE ).build();
```

Log:

```
SEVERE: Failed to create Guice container from all the plugins
com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/scribe/oauth/OAuthService;
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:397)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.get(MembersInjectorStore.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:36)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.apply(FailableCache.java:38)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:506)
    at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor$1.run(AbstractBindingProcessor.java:171)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.initializeBindings(ProcessedBindingData.java:44)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:123)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:71)
    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder.<init>(ExtensionFinder.java:282)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at net.java.sezpoz.IndexItem.instance(IndexItem.java:181)
    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz._find(ExtensionFinder.java:625)
    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz.find(ExtensionFinder.java:600)
    at hudson.ExtensionFinder._find(ExtensionFinder.java:151)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:318)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:295)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:248)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.iterator(ExtensionList.java:138)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:311)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:295)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:248)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.get(ExtensionList.java:153)
    at hudson.PluginManager$PluginUpdateMonitor.getInstance(PluginManager.java:1066)
    at hudson.maven.PluginImpl.init(PluginImpl.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at hudson.init.InitializerFinder.invoke(InitializerFinder.java:120)
    at hudson.init.InitializerFinder$TaskImpl.run(InitializerFinder.java:184)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:259)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:888)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:187)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/scribe/oauth/OAuthService;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2300)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1745)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:651)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:358)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.createWithListeners(MembersInjectorStore.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.access$000(MembersInjectorStore.java:35)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:43)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.apply(FailableCache.java:38)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 71 more
Jun 3, 2013 11:37:17 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
```

Answer (score 0):

What ever you need in your plugin, you specify the same in dependencies.

Reason 1:

> Jenkins loads each plugin into a separate class loader to avoid conflicts. Plugins can then participate to the system activities just like other Jenkins built-in classes do. They can participate in XStream-based persistence, they can provide "views" by Jelly, they can provide static resources like images, and from users, everything works seamlessly --- there's no distinction between functionalities that are built-in vs those from plugins.

Reason 2: You don't want to change your code when jenkins change their dependencies.